# Paramcoq: Free theorems in Coq

Tags: coq, parametric-polymorphism, coq-plugin, free-theorem

How can I prove the following [free theorem](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf) with the plugin [Paramcoq](https://github.com/coq-community/paramcoq)?

```
Lemma id_free (f : forall A : Type, A -> A) (X : Type) (x : X), f X x = x.
```

If it is not possible, then what is the purpose of this plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin can generate the statement of parametricity for any type. You will still need to then declare it as an axiom or an assumption to actually use it:

```
Declare ML Module "paramcoq".

Definition idt := forall A:Type, A -> A.
Parametricity idt arity 1.
(* ^^^ This command defines the constant idt_P. *)

Axiom param_idt : forall f, idt_P f.

Lemma id_free (f : forall A : Type, A -> A) (X : Type) (x : X) : f X x = x.
Proof.
  intros. 
  apply (param_idt f X (fun y => y = x) x).
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: By the way in the documentation's examples, they use `Require Import Parametricity` instead of `Declare ML Module "paramcoq"`. But Coq cannot find this library. Any idea? I have installed Paramcoq with Opam.

Comment: @Bob It would be awesome to let the maintainers know about this. Could you open an issue on GitHub?

Comment: @Bob there is a file Parametricity.v in the paramcoq test-suite director, and then the example.v file in the same directory includes it.